# ionic firebase functions are not responding and even giving no error

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework

I have a question about firebase connection.

When using e.g. signInWithEmailAndPassword in my ionic project, suddenly the function does not give any answers - no error and result.

My code looks like this.

```
login(email, password) {
    this.loadingProvider.show();
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((res) => {
      console.log(res)
      localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', 'true');
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
      this.loadingProvider.hide();
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      this.loadingProvider.hide();
      this.loadingProvider.showToast(err.message)
    })
  }
```

I'm struggeling very hard to find out where the error is, but I don't get any response from all the firebase functions.

Did someone have the same issue and could solve it? I didn't change any credentials of my firebase database or the app itself.

Right now I'm a bit stuck. Any hits are welcome.

Thank you for your help.

my environment:

Ionic:

Ionic CLI                     : 6.11.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.9.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.24
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
@angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
Cordova Platforms : none
Cordova Plugins   : no whitelisted plugins (1 plugins total)

Utility:

cordova-res (update available: 0.15.1) : 0.3.0
native-run                             : not installed

System:

ios-deploy : 1.9.2
ios-sim    : 8.0.2
NodeJS     : v10.15.1 (/usr/local/bin/node)
npm        : 6.14.5
OS         : macOS Catalina
Xcode      : Xcode 11.5 Build version 11E608c
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
this.afAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)...
```

Please remove .auth and try it like this, it should work.